# Bootstrap element structure (containers)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm recently started to work with bootstrap and i really like it, very easy and strcutured.

Although i dont understand one thing, what is the correct structure?

I've read their getting started and they said for example the the first child of row can be column ...

But they also mentioned about div='container', should then also all of the elements be in a container?

for example

```
<div class="container">
   <nav> </navr>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div ....> BODY </div>
</div>

<div class='container">
   <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Or are all of this containers very optional and can be left not used?

Same question about rows, should then all column elements be a part of row or not?

I have following structure:

```
<nav></nav>
<row>
    <div class="col-md-2> </div>
   <div class="col-md-10">
      <row> 
         <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
         <div class="col-md-6"> </div>
      </row>
   </div>
</row>
```

Is this the correct structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `row` has negative margins, it should be placed inside `container`..

According to the Bootstrap docs (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid):

> "***Rows must be placed within a .container for proper alignment and padding.***"

As you'll see in this demo, the non-contained `row` causes a horizontal scrollbar:

http://bootply.com/106752

But, `container` can be used anywhere.. alone, or nested inside other containers / rows.

Comment: but are the containers required? so basically then it means that only when i use rows i should put all rows in one container? or should each row go to a different container?

Comment: `row` should be place inside a `container`... other than that containers are not required. you can use multiple `row` inside a `container` (no need to have a separate container for each)